# Content not displayed by Expander in ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listviewitem, expander

I have the following setup that you can see here

```
<ListView>
       <ListViewItem x:Name="ItemHome" Height="60">
          <ListViewItem.Content>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <materialDesign:PackIcon
                           Width="25"
                           Height="25"
                           Margin="10"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Kind="Database" />
                   <Expander
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Background="{x:Null}"
                           FontFamily="20"
                           Header="TEST">
                    <Expander.Content>
                           <StackPanel Background="Green" Orientation="Vertical">
                                         <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                               <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                                  Width="25"
                                                  Height="25"
                                                  Margin="10"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  Kind="Octagon" />
                                               <TextBlock
                                                  Margin="20,10"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  FontFamily="20"
                                                  Text="TEST" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                         </ListViewItem>
                                         <ListViewItem Height="60">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                               <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                                  Width="25"
                                                  Height="25"
                                                  Margin="10"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  Kind="Needle" />
                                               <TextBlock
                                                  Margin="20,10"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  FontFamily="20"
                                                  Text="TEST" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                         </ListViewItem>
                                      </StackPanel>
                                   </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                             </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem.Content>
          </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

And the issue is that I believe I messed up somehow the code because when I hit the expand button nothing shows up. Tried to give a height/width to the expander content but no luck. The expander buttons shows that he is expanded but nothing more. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting **Height** property of **ListViewItem**:
[image]

This causes the item to never grow. Removing this assignment and making a few more adjustments you get something that works (**NOTE**: I replace materialDesign:PackIcon by my ctl:SymbolIcon, anyone can use any icon or image):

```
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem x:Name="ItemHome">                
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                        
                    <ctl:SymbolIcon Symbol="Calendar" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Expander VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="20" Header="TEST" Margin="0,10,10,10">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <ListViewItem Height="60" Background="ForestGreen">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ctl:SymbolIcon Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Symbol="Send" 
                                                        Foreground="White"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="20,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="20" Text="TEST" 
                                                   Foreground="White"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ListViewItem>
                                <ListViewItem Height="60" Margin="0,1,0,0" Background="ForestGreen">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ctl:SymbolIcon Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Symbol="Accept" 
                                                        Foreground="White"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="20,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="20" Text="TEST" 
                                                   Foreground="White"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ListViewItem>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </Expander>
                </StackPanel>                
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I dont know how I missed that. Thank you!